# Android kotlin viewlifecycleowner sometimes is null in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, lifecycle

In my fragment, I use viewlifecycleowner to observe live data but in some cases my app crashes with this log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't access the Fragment View's LifecycleOwner when getView() is null i.e., before onCreateView() or after onDestroyView()
```

So I ask how to reproduce and avoid this issue please!

Comment: how to reproduce: call it before onCreateView() or after onDestroyView(), how to avoid: do not call it before onCreateView() or after onDestroyView()

Comment: "i use viewlifecycleowner to observe live data" - observers that update views should be setup inside `onViewCreated` at which point `viewlifecycleowner` is never null.

Comment: You can use activity context , by using `requireActivity()` , but if not handled properly it'll create leaks.

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should register your `LiveData` observer in `Fragment`'s `onViewCreated`. where `viewlifecycleowner` [can never be `null`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getViewLifecycleOwner()).

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel.someLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<Something> { 
        // Update the UI.
    })
}
```

Comment: The deprecation of onActivityCreated can be the cause ? because i still make my initialisation inside it

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `observe(this@yourfragment)` instead `observe(viewlifecycleowner)`. And add `@SuppressLint("FragmentLiveDataObserve")` on the top  of the method.

This work for me.